# Rest api sometimes return string some times return json object

Tags: android, spring, spring-boot, rest

I am an android dev, a memeber of front end team. Recently I was debugging a part of android code that was not written by me. It was some other guy who developed it. I saw that android code calls a rest api which returns a json object but sometimes it may return a string. I was surprised that back end is returning different types of responses. I should note that Retrofit 2 is the library we use for api calls. It is not possible to define Data classes in retrofit interface and get string as response, but the android developer handled it in view layer which is violating mvvm architecture.
My question is that by the way it is possible to return different types in rest responses, is it Ok or better say is it wise to do this way? Should I take any actions againts our dear backend developers to stop providing services like that?
Just in case our backend rechnology is Spring boot.

Comment: I'd recommend returning a DTO from the backend. https://www.baeldung.com/java-dto-pattern.

Comment: No, it's not acceptable. The backend should send a particular data structure.

Answer (score 0):

Your backend services should return the same data structure every time. Front-end developers shouldn't have to worry about that. I'd say you bring it out to the backend team to investigate that, and I wouldn't do any workaround to fix that on the Android side.